# WP7 Trouble populating pie chart

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I'm having some trouble with populating a pie chart in my WP7 project. At the moment, my code is as follows below. I've tried a few different ways to bring the data back from an xml web service but no luck. Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

The error I'm getting right now is, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
XDocument XDocument = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));

        XElement Traffic = XDocument.Descendants("traffic").First();
        XElement Quota = XDocument.Descendants("traffic").Attributes("quota");

        ObservableCollection<PieChartItem> Data = new ObservableCollection<PieChartItem>()
        {
            new PieChartItem {Title = "Traffic", Value = (double)Traffic},
            new PieChartItem {Title = "Quota", Value = (double)Quota},
        };

        pieChart1.DataSource = Data;
```

Comment: What does the XML file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is this line has the compile error:

```
XElement Quota = XDocument.Descendants("traffic").Attributes("quota");
```

the result of `Descendants("traffic")` is an `IEnumerable`, not an `XElement`.  in the line above that you're already getting `First` of that enumerable, which is the item you want, isn't it?

the quota line should be:

```
XElement Quota = Traffic.Attributes("quota");
```

Style wise, most people make local variables lower cased, like `traffic` and `quota` and `data` to distinguish them from class level properties and members.

**Update:** it looks like `Attributes("quota")` returns `IEnumerable<XAttribute>`, so that quota line should be:

```
XAttribute Quota = Traffic.Attributes("quota").FirstOrDefault();
```

or to simplify:

```
var traffic = XDocument.Descendants("traffic").First();   
var quota = traffic.Attributes("quota").FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't want to be *mean*, but fixing compiler errors like this should be something you shouldn't have to come to stackoverflow for.  The compiler error itself is telling you what the problem is: the method returns a type other than what *you* said it does.  Using `var` can simplify some of that.

Comment: Looks like this is the issue.